# NumPy fill method on a scalar

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, scalar

In the following code

```
a = numpy.array([1,2,3])
b = a[0]
b.fill(5)
print(b)
print(a)
```

No error is raised. However, it prints 1 for `b`. I expected 5. Why this?

Comment: Note that `b = a[:1]` does return the expected results.

Comment: Your `b`  is an `np.int32` object, not a single element array.  While it has some of the same methods, it is not identical.  So while you can index it with `b[()]`, you can't assign a value.  `b[:1]` is a view of `a`; `b[[0]]` is a shape (1,) copy.